# Processing - lines get bigger progressively

Tags: time, processing, lines

so I have in a file the coordinates and the seconds I want to make a line get bigger progressively. In the file, I have x1, x2 (regarding the first point coordinates), x2, y2 (2nd point coordinates), and the time (in seconds) I want to start growing the line, in the second point direction.

This is my code:

//TO READ LINES

```java
import processing.video.*;
Movie myMovie;
Table table;
float duration, time;

int row_no=1;
int clickcount = 0;

void setup() {
  size(640,480);
  myMovie = new Movie(this, "draft.mov");
  myMovie.loop();


  table = loadTable("data/new.csv");

}

void draw() {

duration = myMovie.duration();
time = myMovie.time();
image(myMovie, 0, 0);  

if(time>= table.getFloat(row_no, 4)){
strokeWeight(15);
stroke(255,14,255);

float a = table.getFloat(row_no, 0);
float b = table.getFloat(row_no,1);

line(table.getFloat(row_no,0),table.getFloat(row_no, 1), a, b);

a = a + 2;
b = b + 2;
}



}
    // Called every time a new frame is available to read

void movieEvent(Movie m) {
  m.read();
} `
```

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't really designed for general "how do I do this" type questions. It's for more specific "I tried X, expected Y, but got Z instead" type questions. You need to [break your problem down](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/how-to/program). The question you are asking is unclear, so try and edit the question in order to: ask what you want to do, show how you've previously tried to do it without success, and show the outcome of your failed attempts.

Comment: Can you please narrow your problem down to a [mcve] instead of your whole project? Your question doesn't have anything to do with the movie, does it? So just start with a more basic sketch that just shows the lines growing. We also don't have access to the file, so please just use hardcoded numbers instead.

Answer (score 0):

As Niccolo advises, break your problem down first, take out anything you don't need and go one step at a time.

In terms or taking stuff out, based on the description of your goals, it doesn't sound like code has anything to do with playing back a movie, so take that code out to simplify. (The only reason I could think of for using a movie is to use it's current time to control the lines, but unless you want a movie background you shouldn't need that)

In the draw() loop there are a few things that look odd:

1. `if(time>= table.getFloat(row_no, 4)){` assuming the 5th column in the .csv file holds the cue time for the current row in seconds, this condition will trigger only once potentially as there's nothing incrementing `row_no`
2. `line(table.getFloat(row_no,0),table.getFloat(row_no, 1), a, b);` isn't probably what you're after and might be a typo because `a` and `b` have retrieved from the same .csv columns (0 and 1), which means you're line's start and end position are in the exact position (therefore not rendering a line). perhaps you meant `line(table.getFloat(row_no,2),table.getFloat(row_no, 3), a, b);` ?
3. `a = a + 2;` and `b = b + 2;`: the x,y positions for one of the points may be offset by 2, but the new positions are never used past this point. In the next `draw()` iteration `a` and `b` are redefined, and therefore the offset is lost.

Let's go through breaking the problem down:

> I have in a **file** the **coordinates and the seconds** I want to make a line get bigger progressively. In the file, I have x1, x2 (regarding the first point coordinates), x2, y2 (2nd point coordinates), and the time (in seconds) I want to start growing the line, in the second point direction.

1. load and parse the data (rows containing line coordinates (x1,y1,x2,y2) and time(in seconds))
2. "make a line get bigger progressively" - animate (interpolate) between the current line (.csv row coordinates) and the next line based on the specified time in seconds)

and even further, if starting from scratch, more as a "how to":

1. interpolate between one value an another (ignoring time for now, keeping task independent and as simple as possible)
2. keep track of time as a parameter for interpolating between values
3. parsing .csv rows
4. interpolating between 4 four values
5. incrementing .csv rows based on animation time

Luckily, Processing provides a built-in function for linearly interpolating between values [lerp()](https://processing.org/reference/lerp_.html)(lerp = linear interpolation for short).
It takes three parameters:

1. a value to animate from (start)
2. a value to animate to (stop)
3. an interpolation amount (between 0.0 and 1.0)

and it returns one value: the value in between the start and stop values.
Think of the interpolation amount as a percentage (0 = 0%, 0.5 = 50%, 1.0 = 100%).

Here's a basic sketch to illustrate the concept:

```
void draw(){
  background(255);
  //map time to an interpolation normalized value 
  float t = map(mouseX,0,width,0.0,1.0);
  //interpolate the values
  float size = lerp(10,90,constrain(t,0.0,1.0));
  ellipse(50,50,size,size);
}
```

the snippet a p5.js demo you can run bellow:

```js
function setup() {
  createCanvas(100,100);
}

function draw(){
  background(255);
  //map time to an interpolation normalized value 
  var t = map(mouseX,0,width,0.0,1.0);
  //interpolate the values
  var size = lerp(10,90,constrain(t,0.0,1.0));
  ellipse(50,50,size,size);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.11/p5.min.js"></script>
```

if you move your mouse on the x axis you'll notice the size goes between 10 and 90 pixels in diameter based on the mouse position.

Step 1 done!

Next up, you can use [`millis()`](https://processing.org/reference/millis_.html) to keep track of time and simply [`map()`](https://processing.org/reference/millis_.html) between time in millis (mapping the current time between the start and end time to the 0.0 - 1.0 range):

```
float seconds = 3.5;

//the time in millis since the last update
int previousMillis;
//the current time in millis 
int currentMillis;
//the time in millis until the next event
int nextMillis;



void setup(){

  previousMillis = millis();
  currentMillis = millis();

  nextMillis = currentMillis + (int)(seconds * 1000);

}

void draw(){
  background(255);
  //update the current timer continously
  currentMillis = millis();
  //map the current time from the previous to the next time as a normalized value (0,0 to 1.0) range
  float t = map(currentMillis,previousMillis,nextMillis,0.0,1.0);

  //interpolate the values
  float size = lerp(10,90,constrain(t,0.0,1.0));
  ellipse(50,50,size,size);
}
```

and as a p5.js runnable demo:

```js
var seconds = 3.5;

//the time in millis since the last update
var previousMillis;
//the current time in millis 
var currentMillis;
//the time in millis until the next event
var nextMillis;



function setup(){

  previousMillis = millis();
  currentMillis = millis();

  nextMillis = currentMillis + (int)(seconds * 1000);

}

function draw(){
  background(255);
  //update the current timer continously
  currentMillis = millis();
  //map the current time from the previous to the next time as a normalized value (0,0 to 1.0) range
  var t = map(currentMillis,previousMillis,nextMillis,0.0,1.0);

  //interpolate the values
  var size = lerp(10,90,constrain(t,0.0,1.0));
  ellipse(50,50,size,size);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.11/p5.min.js"></script>
```

That's step2 done and it looks like you've got a hand of step 3 (parsing the .csv values) already :)

Step 4 should be trivial once you understand how to interpolate one value: just do it 4 times for different variables!

Step 5 is simple as you simply need to check if `row_no` goes beyond the table's row count.

```
row_no = row_no + 1;
if(row_no > table.getRowCount()) row_no = 0;
```

One neat thing you could do is use the [modulo operator(%)](https://processing.org/reference/modulo.html) to do the same as a mathematical expression:

```
row_no = (row_no + 1) % table.getRowCount();
```

In conclusion, let's assume you're .csv file looks a little like this:

```
x1,y1,x2,y2,seconds
5,5,95,5,4
95,5,95,95,3
95,95,5,95,2
5,95,5,5,1
```

One way to put it all together would be something like this:

```
Table table;
int row_no = 0;

//the time in millis since the last update
int previousMillis;
//the current time in millis 
int currentMillis;
//the time in millis until the next event
int nextMillis;

//where to animate the line from
float x1Start,y1Start,x2Start,y2Start;
//where to animate the line to 
float x1Stop,y1Stop,x2Stop,y2Stop;
//currently interpolated line positions
float x1Lerp,y1Lerp,x2Lerp,y2Lerp;

void setup(){
  size(100,100);
  strokeWeight(3);
  fill(0);

  table = loadTable("data/new.csv","header, csv");

  //printing the table in console, handy just for debugging/double checking values
  println("data");
  for(int i = 0 ; i <= table.getRowCount(); i++){
    print(table.getColumnTitle(i)+"\t");
  }
  println();
  for(int i = 0 ; i < table.getRowCount(); i++){
    TableRow row = table.getRow(i);
    for(int j = 0; j < row.getColumnCount(); j++){
      print(row.getFloat(j) + "\t");
    }
    println();
  } 
  //fetch lines and seconds from the current and next rows
  updateFromRow();
}

void updateFromRow(){
  //update times
  previousMillis = millis();
  currentMillis = millis();

  //get the current row and it's line coordinates
  TableRow currentRow = table.getRow(row_no);
  x1Start     = currentRow.getFloat("x1");
  y1Start     = currentRow.getFloat("y1");
  x2Start     = currentRow.getFloat("x2");
  y2Start     = currentRow.getFloat("y2");
  //get the next row and it's line coordinates - notice % module is used to easily loop back to 0 once row_no goes beyond the number of table rows 
  TableRow nextRow = table.getRow((row_no + 1) % table.getRowCount());
  x1Stop     = nextRow.getFloat("x1");
  y1Stop     = nextRow.getFloat("y1");
  x2Stop     = nextRow.getFloat("x2");
  y2Stop     = nextRow.getFloat("y2");
  //get the duration in seconds, convert it to millis( * 1000) and add it to the current millis
  nextMillis = currentMillis + (int)(currentRow.getFloat("seconds") * 1000);

  println("updated from row: " + row_no);
}

void draw(){
  background(255);
  //update the current timer continously
  currentMillis = millis();
  //map the current time from the previous to the next time as a normalized value (0,0 to 1.0) range
  float t = map(currentMillis,previousMillis,nextMillis,0.0,1.0);
  //if the current interpolation value is above 1.0 
  if(t > 1.0){
    t = 0;
    //increment the row
    row_no++;
    //if the current row counter is above the total number of rows, reset back 0
    if(row_no >= table.getRowCount()){
      row_no = 0;
    }
    //update values from incremented row (lines and their coordinates + time)
    updateFromRow();
  }
  text("t:"+t,15,20);

  //constrain interpolated value between 0.0 and 1.0
  float interpolationAmount = constrain(t,0.0,1.0);
  //linearly interpolate (lerp) between the current and next line coordinates
  x1Lerp = lerp(x1Start,x1Stop,interpolationAmount);
  y1Lerp = lerp(y1Start,y1Stop,interpolationAmount);
  x2Lerp = lerp(x2Start,x2Stop,interpolationAmount);
  y2Lerp = lerp(y2Start,y2Stop,interpolationAmount);

  //finally, render the interpolated line 
  line(x1Lerp,y1Lerp,x2Lerp,y2Lerp);
}
```

In terms of keeping track of the data, the line coordinates can be stored using [PVector](http://processing.org/reference/PVector.html) instances (...the x,y components [set()](https://processing.org/reference/PVector_set_.html) from .csv data and the line points can be interpolated in pairs via [PVector's lerp()](https://processing.org/reference/PVector_lerp_.html)).
So far we've only been using linear interpolation, but you might also want to look into [easing](https://processing.org/examples/easing.html) and [tweening](http://benedikt-gross.de/libraries/Ani/).